# codeigniter not working in nginx(running on localhost), linux mint

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, nginx, url-rewriting

I have installed LEMP on my linux mint system.
nginx is configured to work with php5-fpm sockets.
When I run codeigniter in my system index.php(link: localhost/ci/index.php) shows up, but when I try to open any of controller, say blog(link localhost/ci/index.php/blog) nginx gives **404 error** message.

Following is my nginx configuration placed in file /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default

```
server {
listen 127.0.0.1:80;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
root /home/scoders/Workspace/public_html;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
autoindex on;

server_name localhost;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/scoders/Workspace/public_html/ci/index.php;
    #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

Contents of nginx.conf are as follows:

```
user scoders;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}
http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
}
```

My log gives following error:

```
    2016/03/14 14:38:38 [error] 23239#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: 
"Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /ci/index.php/ci 
HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "localhost"
```

I have tried  these links but no luck:

[Codeigniter | NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/)

[CodeIgniter NGINX Rewrite Rules](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-nginx-rewrite-rules/)

Comment: Is the file name of blog.php or Blog.php should be first letter upper case.

Comment: controller name is Blog.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `/home/scoders/Workspace/public_html/ci/index.php` is inaccessible for some reason or `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is being overridden in `include fastcgi_params;`

As a general rule, you should `include` first and `fastcgi_param` after.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Also, if your default URI is `/ci/index.php` and not `/index.php`, change your `location /` to:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /ci/index.php?$args;
}
```

Comment: just by prepending  /ci to /index.php?$args it worked, although I have made both the changes. Thanks..